# Archive java code into .jar with external libraries, but unpacked or in a more "lean" way

Tags: java, maven, build, executable-jar

I usually use Intellij on my day to day, and I know I can create an artifactory and use Maven Assembly Plugin to create a .jar file.

From what I can see both of these tools unpack the external libraries (dependencies) .jar files and merging them with my code before creating the .jar with my code.

Some questions would be:

1. Can I by terminal/Maven/Other-tool have these external .jar files packed in mine or will that never work? i thought `java -jar` was able to see files in packed .jars
2. If 1 is not possible, then Is there not a more efficient way of unpacking these libraries? I only wanted to use StringUtils from apache.commons-lang but I intead had to have the entire commons-lang.jar (unpacked) in my .jar. Could there not be a more efficient "merge"?

Comment: First to use classes from a library you don't need to unpack that jar file or library. Define that lib as a dependency and you can use it... Furthermore if you like to create a ueber-jar which means contains all of your dependencies (executable jar)...this exectuable jar/ueber jar can be achieved by using maven-assembly-plugin or maven-shade-plugin The assembly-plugin is not the main purpose to create a jar file ... that is the job of maven-jar-plugin...